# Count number of times database is accessed on a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

For context, I am a fairly new to ASP.Net, C#, and LINQ, and have recently come to be in charge of a site that is heavily depended on data from a database. Also, not sure if it matters, but the main app code is on a server separate from the DB.

**My Question:** Is there a way to "count" the number of times the application accesses the database on a given page? Pretty much all data is being accessed through LINQ (which has been set up to work with our database in a separate solution). On most pages within the site, there are multiple loops based on (changing) data from the DB, with each loop executing multiple LINQ queries inside.

Basic Example from my code:

```
foreach(Answer ans in targetUser.UserAnswers.Select(ua => ua.Answer)
{
  AnswerName.innerText = ans.Name;
  AnswerDesc.innerHtml = ans.Description;
  //etc
}
//etc
```

Except in reality, there are many loops (including further nested loops), and so it is really difficult to estimate how many times the database is being hit with every page load.

I guess a followup question would be, is the database accessed 'separately' every time I use LINQ? I would imagine that every time we do "ans.Name" (for example), the database would have to be accessed again. In this case, I suppose one solution would be manually incrementing a count variable everywhere in the code where LINQ is used.

If my question is confusing, please let me know and I will revise it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put Miniprofiler into your application. Also, is this Webforms or MVC? Are you referring to Linq-To-Objects; Linq-To-Entities; or Linq-To-SQL? Those are three separate technologies that all use a Linq Interface. In two cases they talk to a database using an ORM, in the third case; it's just a way to use set based logic over a collection.

Comment: For the most part, all LINQ queries are only executed against the database when the items are accessed, either by a method like `Count()`, or `ToList()`.

Comment: The `foreach` will trigger a database query. Reading `ans.Name` won't -- it's just reading fields out of the resultset the database has already returned.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Great questions. For #1, Webforms, but I'm not sure about the others. Is there a quick way of checking how LINQ is set up?

Comment: @JoeWhite Thanks, that's helpful. How about if I do ans.Attribute.Name? (Attribute is another table in the DB connected to Answer). Would that be a separate query?

Comment: @Swquenzer Since it's your application, I imagine you'd trace down the stack until you find a reference to a namespace you don't own.  Or look in your project references for EntityFramework or System.Data.Linq; If you're not sure what you're using for Data Access; you should probably ask someone on your team.

Comment: Every foreach statement executes the query. The same is with Count, Max, Average, and First. They execute query without an explicit foreach statement because the query itself must use foreach in order to return a result.

Comment: @Swquenzer, yes, that would be another database call -- by default it only loads the table itself, and then lazy-loads related tables only when you access them. But you can tell it to eagerly load Attribute as part of the original query, by changing `.Select(...)` to `.Select(...).Include(ans => ans.Attribute)` -- i.e., opting in to including the Attribute table before you do the `foreach`.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Gotcha, sorry for my ignorance, this project kinda fell in my lap. Unfortunately the data solution references both System.Data.Linq AND System.Data.Entity, so I can't be sure. Thanks for your help though! Also that "Includes" method is nifty, I'm glad you mentioned it.

Comment: Methods ToList() and ToArray() also execute query but they cache its result.

Comment: @rba Thanks for the info, those extra tips are extremely helpful to me right now!

Comment: @Swquenzer Another thing to do would be to look for EDMX files or DBML Files; the former is what Entity Framework uses to generate a class schema for your DB; the latter is what Linq-To-SQL uses.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Perfect, there's a nice EDMX file in place, so we must be using Entity Framework. Good to know.